# Java EE: Getting parameters from POST for a login form

Tags: java, html, xml, servlets

I am trying to implement a simple login servlet but it's not working properly.

**What I wanted to know** is how to pass the parameters using a HTTP POST. It already works with HTTP GET but the username and password are visible from the URL. It would be better to hide them in a POST.

```
<form method="post" action="home" >
  <input name="username" class="form-login" title="Username" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" />
  <input name="password" type="password" class="form-login" title="Password" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" />
  <input type="submit" value="Connect">
</form>
```

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.HomeController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**Servlet:**

```
public class HomeController extends HttpServlet {

    private HttpSession session;
    private UserBean userBean;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        UserBean user = new UserBean();
        String userName = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        user.setUsername(userName);
        user.setPassword(password);

        user = UserDAO.login(user);

        dispatch(request, response, ApplicationRessource.getInstance().getHomePage());
    }

    protected void dispatch(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, String page)
            throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(page);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `userName` and `password` strings are always empty, meaning that the parameters are never fetched from the POST. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know much from servlets, but in HTML you should put in the action="home" the page  where you are going to recieve those parameters, action"home.jsp" also, I dont know if you need to specifiy the <input name="username" id="username" />

Comment: What browser are you using?

Please try adding encytype (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) it should be the default though...

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Comment: It probably isn't important but the first input misses a type="text" attribute (though it's the default I think)

Comment: Swap getParameter with getAttribute and check whether that works...

Comment: @helios, I tried your advice, but both the `parameterMap` and the `attributes` are null

Comment: try putting the url for the servlet into the action attribute

Comment: @chad, makes no sense! Because `home` is mapped to my HomeController in the web.xml

Comment: @JFB you didn't state that and I'm not psychic

Comment: no sweat ChadNC! I admit that could of been problematic.

Comment: Apart from the concrete problem which is not answerable based on the information provided so far, declaring `session` and `userBean` as instance variables of the servlet is a bad idea. They will be shared by **all users** visiting the web application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work, can you check by changing form method to get and trying, you should see parameters in url.

Comment: Funny thing, it works when changing from method=post to method=get and using `doGet` instead of `doPost`

Comment: Only thing, it's unfortunate to see the password in the url, I still think it's beter to use a POST even if you can sniff the text using wireshark.

Comment: you should use post for sure :-), it was just for test. Can you try in some other browser

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

In your doPost(..) method code only doGet(..) and put all your logic in doGet(..) and check if still it is giving blank values.

Let me know what is the output.

Example:-

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
           doGet(request,response);
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        UserBean user = new UserBean();
        String userName = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        user.setUsername(userName);
        user.setPassword(password);

        user = UserDAO.login(user);

        dispatch(request, response, ApplicationRessource.getInstance().getHomePage());
    }
```

Comment: the parameters are still in the url

Comment: Parameters are in the url because i guess you are using "get" in your jsp. Use "post" only in your jsp and try implementing the above code. What will happen is from your servlet's "doPost" method, "doGet" will be called. Let me know what is the output.

Answer (score 0):

this simple implementation should have worked ..but since its not, there maybe some code which is manipulating the request. The code you have posted is not sufficient to determine that.

Some pointers I can give are -

1. Check your `web.xml` to see if there is any filter/interceptor which is manipulating the request.
2. Which web/app server are you using? Have you checked the `service(Http...)` method implementation of HttpServlet. You can `try placing a debug point in service(..) method` to see if the request object here has the required request parameters. If it doesn't, then the problem exists either in some filter or your jsp itself.
3. What does `dispatch(request, response, ApplicationRessource.getInstance().getHomePage());` do? I know the problem is before this line, but this is not a standard HttpServlet method, so I assume there's lot more custom code then whats been posted in the question above.

Comment: I have edited my original post with the web.xml and the dispatch method

Comment: 1) The tomcat's service(..) method implementation is pretty simple and it just forwards the request to doGet(..) or doPost(..) based on request.getMethod() condition.  if you haven't overridden service(..) method than there is not much to look in here. 2) Do you have any filters declared in your web.xml or any filter based annotations anywhere?

Comment: I do not use annotations, and I have no filter tags in my `web.xml`. The `dispatch()` method follows the Page Controller or Front Controller design pattern (see: http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/FrontController.html)

Comment: Are you saying that the `service()` method would not be useful in this case?

Comment: there is no problem with your dispatch(..) method. The point which I was making earlier was that I see more custom code than what was originally posted in your question. `Are you saying that the service() method would not be useful in this case`....have you overridden service method? if not, then everything is fine with service method.